# Emisson pass over Glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass, emission

everyone!
I came across a problem with emitting light through Glass in *Cycles* - a police siren - No matter what Emission value I set, it stays this dim.

[image: Preview]

*Glass:

Glass BSDF

IOR: 1.450

Roughness: 0.0*

*Emission

Basically setting any value higher than **1000** has no effect*

I tried lowering the IOR of glass, mixing with transparent node, that however created very strange, burned, overexposed effect with the light being pink.

**P.S. I want to avoid multiple Render layers**, though for now it seems like the only option, or even if possible at all.

I would love to achieve this effect:

[image: Target]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: did u try glare node?

Comment: I'm wondering like @Chris if you tried compositing or do you expect it to glow just by increasing the strength? These glows and lens flares etc. which you see in real photographs are usually an effect of overblown light sensors in cameras, lens imperfections and don'T let me get too technical here, but a virtual camera in 3D software doesn't have this. All is rendered crisp and clear until you go and create something like glow effects in compositing. Also things like depth of field or motion blur do not happen naturally with virtual cameras unless you tell them to calculate such things.

Comment: For the light getting pink, well that depeds on what basic color you have set for the light. For example if you have RGB (1, 0, 0) than it will mostly stay completely red, since green and blue are not present and multiplying with some strength doesn't increase them (if _Color Management_ is set to _Standard_, but _Filmic_ might change these base values). If however your green and blue values are > 0, then they will change the color the higher the emission strength is. A higher blue will make it pink, a higher green will make it orange. Until the strength is so high that it gets all white.

Comment: I found the problem to be in the Glass shader itself - since it did not pass enough light, it was not the problem of Emission being pink (the RGB node was full red). When I adjusted the glass (for a more realistic one also) node, the light was way more bright, able to be composited later on also. Hope my last post explains... Thanks guys anyway for digging into it, appretiate it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this nodes setup in compositing:

[image]

material:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion with glare, however the problem was with the Glass. Just in case of anyone interested I am posting my solution:

I brewed this material for the *transparent cover* of the siren, that allows to *pass way more light* from the emission

[image: Glass material]

Glass before:

[image: Glass BSDF only]

Glass after:

[image: Glass composed]

I played with the **compositing** also to get control over the **Glare effect**, since it created strong outlines on default value:

[image: Compositing]

This is the **final result** I am satisfied with *(I did not go for the full light effect at the end)*

[image: Final result]